# Format numbers to significant figures nicely in R

Tags: r

I want to format numbers in my reports to [significant digits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_digits), but keep trailing significant zeroes and correctly format large numbers

For instance the numbers c(10.00001,12345,1234.5,123.45,1.2345,0.12345) to 3 significant digits should be 10.0, 12300, 1230, 123,  1.23, 0.123 but I get differing results with different methods (and none seem to work universaly.

```
> numbers<-c(10.00001,12345,1234.5,123.45,1.2345,0.12345)
> for(n in seq(numbers)){
+   print(signif(numbers[n],digits=3))
+   print(format(numbers[n],digits=3))
+   print(formatC(numbers[n], digits=3,format="fg"))
+   print(formatC(numbers[n], digits=3,format="fg", flag="#"))
+   }
[1] 10
[1] "10"
[1] "  10"
[1] "10.0"
[1] 12300
[1] "12345"
[1] "12345"
[1] "12345."
[1] 1230
[1] "1234"
[1] "1234"
[1] "1234."
[1] 123
[1] "123"
[1] " 123"
[1] "123."
[1] 12.3
[1] "12.3"
[1] "12.3"
[1] "12.3"
[1] 1.23
[1] "1.23"
[1] "1.23"
[1] "1.23"
[1] 0.123
[1] "0.123"
[1] "0.123"
[1] "0.123"
```

Here, signif and format round the 10.00001 result.  formatC with flag="#" correctly does the small numbers but not the large numbers.

Is there a better way ?

Comment: also try apply, lapply and sapply instead of looping...

Comment: I may have a gross conceptual error, but doesn't the `apply` family of functions still use loops? But it abstracts away the loops for the code is cleaner and easier to read, with less housekeeping. Right?

Comment: Sorry, the loop is there just to show the results, I originaly had signif(numbers,digits=3) but that defaulted to scientific notation for some reason.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by your statement.  Some of the apply family, in some cases, are looping in C, not R.  lapply has optimizations that make it faster than for loops.  aggregate(), and tapply() are much faster than loops in R.  You also leave your code open for further optimizations.  In regards to your initial question, help(format).

Comment: Just a comment that something's a little off in your 4 significant figure examples... they should be rounding to , e.g., `1235` (i.e. because the 5 rounds the 4 up)... just as in `round(.123456,digits=4)` giving `[1] 0.1235`. Thank you for the question, though! +1

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Sorry I never updated this at the time.  None of the statements in my question, or prettynum worked.  In the end I used

```
print(formatC(signif(numbers[n], digits=3), digits=3, format="fg", flag="#"))
```

which correctly coped with trailing zero's and big numbers.

Comment: Happy to see that using `formatC()` was the solution [as I ported that function to R,  and notably introduced `format = "fg"` myself with quite some consideration.  Typically, nowadays, `sprintf()` is often preferred to formatC(), but indeed, I don't see a nice way to get the solution via sprintf() instead of formatC().

BTW: Given your `numbers`, I found it convenient to use `sapply` instead of the for loop
`sapply(numbers, function(N) formatC(signif(N, digits=3), digits=3,format="fg", flag="#"))`

Comment: doesn't `formatC` with `fg` find the significant digits, so `signif` is unneeded?

Comment: formatC helped with my last formatting requirements. I found I had to ifelse it, having "digits=0, format="f"" for inputs >=1, and " digits=1, format="fg"" for values < 1 in order to get what I needed.

Comment: Thanks @MartinMächler for your `sappy`-solution.

Answer (score 22):

Are you aware of `prettyNum()` and all its options?

Comment: any tips how to format numeric to character: `1000 -> 1k`, `10000 -> 10k`, `1000000 -> 1M`, `1e7 -> 10M`?

Comment: @Jan there is a pretty new package doing that: [prettyunits](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/prettyunits/)

Answer (score 10):

Another modification on Paul's answer. It appears that it also leaves a trailing decimal. I am removing it with gsub:

```
sigfig <- function(vec, digits){
  return(gsub("\\.$", "", formatC(signif(vec,digits=digits), digits=digits, format="fg", flag="#")))
}
```

Answer (score 8):

A more barebones option is `options()`, which just does rounding. If you plan on doing this a lot, I suggest checking out Sweave.

```
> a <- 1.23456789
> options(digits=2)
> a
[1] 1.2
> options(digits=6)
> a
[1] 1.23457
```

Answer (score 6):

If you like scientific notation

```
> format(2^31-1, scientific = TRUE, digits = 3)
[1] "2.15e+09"
```

Answer (score 6):

Paul Hurley's method above worked well for me for both positive and negative numbers.  Below is some code which modifies Paul's solution into a function in which the desired significant figures can be specified.

```
sigfig <- function(vec, n=3){ 
### function to round values to N significant digits
# input:   vec       vector of numeric
#          n         integer is the required sigfig  
# output:  outvec    vector of numeric rounded to N sigfig

formatC(signif(vec,digits=n), digits=n,format="fg", flag="#") 

}      # end of function   sigfig
```

to verify it works OK

```
numbers <- c(50000.01, 1000.001, 10.00001, 12345, 1234.5, 123.45, 1.2345, 0.12345, 0.0000123456, -50000.01, -1000.001,-10.00001, -12345, -1234.5, -123.45, -1.2345, -0.12345, -0.0000123456)
sigfig(numbers)   # defaults to 3
sigfig(numbers, 3)
sigfig(numbers, 1)
sigfig(numbers, 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following option replicates the format of `formatC(format="fg",flag="#")` (`fg` is a special version of `f` where the digits specify significant digits and not digits after the decimal point, and the `#` flag causes `fg` to not drop trailing zeroes):

```
> f=2;x=c(10000.0001,1111,111.11,11.1,1.1,1.99,.01,.001,0,-.11,-.9,-.000011)
> dig=abs(pmin(0,floor(log10(abs(x)))-f+1))
> sprintf(paste0("%.",ifelse(is.infinite(dig),0,dig),"f"),x)
 [1] "10000"     "1111"      "111"       "11"        "1.1"       "2.0"
 [7] "0.010"     "0.0010"    "0"         "-0.11"     "-0.90"     "-0.000011"
> sub("\\.$","",formatC(x,f,,"fg","#"))
 [1] "10000"     "1111"      "111"       "11"        "1.1"       "2.0"
 [7] "0.010"     "0.0010"    "0"         "-0.11"     "-0.90"     "-0.000011"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a potentially unwanted behaviour with the answer presented by PaulHurleyuk:

**Tests**

Test 1:

```
numbers <- c(0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000)
print(formatC(signif(numbers, digits = 3), digits = 3, format = "fg", flag = "#"))
```

Returns:

```
[1] "0.000100" "0.00100"  "0.0100"   "0.100"    "1.00"     "10.0"     "100."     "1000."
```

Test 2:

```
numbers <- c(1.0001, 1.001, 1.01, 1.1, 11, 101, 1001, 10001)
print(formatC(signif(numbers,digits=3), digits=3,format="fg", flag="#"))
```

Returns:

```
[1] "1.00"   "1.00"   "1.01"   "1.10"   "11.0"   "101."   "1000."  "10000."
```

Notice the trailing decimal delimiters in both examples and also the introduced trailing zeros in test 1.

**Solution**

To remove the trailing decimal delimiters:

```
gsub("\\.$", "", formatC(signif(numbers, digits = 3), digits = 3,format = "fg", flag = "#"))
```

If used often, make it a function:

```
sigfill <- function(x, sigfigs = 3){
  out <- gsub("\\.$", "",
              formatC(signif(x, digits = sigfigs),
                      digits = sigfigs, format = "fg", flag = "#"))
  return(out)
}
```

To also remove trailing zeros introduced by the previous code:

```
sigfill <- function(x, sigfigs = 3){
  out <- gsub("\\.$", "",
              formatC(signif(x, digits = sigfigs),
                      digits = sigfigs, format = "fg", flag = "#"))
  out[grepl(".", out, fixed = TRUE)] <- strtrim(out[grepl(".", out, fixed = TRUE)],
                                                sigfigs + c(1, 2)[grepl("-", out, fixed = TRUE) + 1])
  return(out)
}
```

**Test again**

Positive numbers:

```
numbers <- c(0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000)
sigfill(numbers)
```

returns

```
[1] "0.00" "0.00" "0.01" "0.10" "1.00" "10.0" "100"  "1000"
```

"Spread out" numbers:

```
numbers <- c(1.0001, 1.001, 1.01, 1.1, 11, 101, 1001, 10001)
sigfill(numbers)
```

returns

```
[1] "1.00"  "1.00"  "1.01"  "1.10"  "11.0"  "101"   "1000"  "10000"
```

Negative numbers:

```
numbers <- c(-0.0001, -0.001, -0.01, -0.1, -1, -10, -100, -1000)
sigfill(numbers)
```

returns

```
[1] "-0.00" "-0.00" "-0.01" "-0.10" "-1.00" "-10.0" "-100"  "-1000"
```

Result: No trailing decimal delimiters or additional trailing zeros.