# How can I get this exact formatting in R?

Tags: r, format, pretty-print

I tried playing around with `signif` or `formatC`, but didn't get the result, no matter which of the options I used. I could write my own function... but I am sure there is a solution.

The following code provides an example data frame. Column `a` presents the numerical input column and column `b` the expected "rendered" character output.

The numbers have to be rounded to three significant digits (e.g. `signif`)

```
> data.frame(a=c(1,23,456,1.23,23.46,456.78,1234),b=c("1.00","23.0","456","1.23","23.5","457","1230"))
        a    b
1    1.00 1.00
2   23.00 23.0
3  456.00  456
4    1.23 1.23
5   23.46 23.5
6  456.78  457
7 1234.00 1230
```

Edit: This is the output for the proposed solution:

```
> df <- data.frame(a=c(1,23,456,1.23,23.46,456.78,1234),b=c("1.00","23.0","456","1.23","23.5","457","1230"))
> df$c <- print(formatC(signif(df$a,digits=3), digits=3,format="fg", flag="#"))
[1] "1.00"  "23.0"  "456."  "1.23"  "23.5"  "457."  "1230."
> df
        a    b     c
1    1.00 1.00  1.00
2   23.00 23.0  23.0
3  456.00  456  456.
4    1.23 1.23  1.23
5   23.46 23.5  23.5
6  456.78  457  457.
7 1234.00 1230 1230.
```

Can we now remove the decimal point for the numbers 456, 457 and 1230?

Comment: To clarify, column "a" is input, "b" column is expected?

Comment: Sorry, yes exactly.

Comment: Please explain the strategy from `a` to `b`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format numbers to significant figures nicely in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245862/format-numbers-to-significant-figures-nicely-in-r)

Comment: Are we trying to keep the numbers within 4 characters?

Comment: Looks like 3 significant figures hence my duplicate flag

Comment: Why `1234.00` becomes `1230` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the `Signif` function from [`VFP`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/VFP/versions/1.0/topics/Signif) package.

```
VFP:::Signif(df$a, 3)
[1] "1.00" "23.0" "456"  "1.23" "23.5" "457"  "1230"
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not proud of this solution, but `gsub`+regex does the job now fine.

```
> df$c <- gsub('\\.$', '',formatC(signif(df$a,digits=3), digits=3,format="fg", flag="#"))
> df
        a    b    c
1    1.00 1.00 1.00
2   23.00 23.0 23.0
3  456.00  456  456
4    1.23 1.23 1.23
5   23.46 23.5 23.5
6  456.78  457  457
7 1234.00 1230 1230
```