# Get the first non zero digit in R similar to Mathematica

Tags: r, wolfram-mathematica, substr, lead

In `mathematica` we have [RealDigits](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RealDigits.html) that can identify the first non-zero number for both numbers with decimal point and integer values. See below as an example:

```
RealDigits[ 0.00318, 10, 1]
{{3},-2}
RealDigits[ 419, 10, 1]
{{4},-2}
```

In the above example the function identifies, 3 and 4 respectively for 0.00318 and 419.

Is there a similar function in `R`?

Comment: take a look at: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2010/04/significant-figures-in-r-and-info-zeros/

Comment: Did you check this threat and solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/3443955/9783433 Maybe it helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do:

```r
x <- c(0.0000318, 419)

as.numeric(substr(formatC(x, format = 'e'), 1, 1))
# [1] 3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

This function will accept vector arguments as well as a `depth` parameter letting you define how many digits you want to have after the first significant one.

```
x <- c(0.00318, 0.000489, 895.12)
RealDigits <- function(x, depth=1) {
  y <- as.character(x)
  ysplit <- strsplit(y,"")
  ysplit <- strsplit(y,"")
  last0 <- lapply(ysplit, function(x) tail(which(x==0),1))
  last00 <- sapply(last0, function(x) if (length(x) ==0) 0 else x )
  res <- substr(y, last00+1, as.numeric(sapply(y, nchar)))
  return(substr(res, 0,depth))
}
RealDigits(x)
RealDigits(x, depth =2)

> RealDigits(x)
[1] "3" "4" "8"
> RealDigits(x, depth =2)
[1] "31" "48" "89"
```