# hypothesis test to compare the means in groups

Tags: r, ggpubr, hypothesis-test

I have the following dataset:

```r
totalamount <- structure(list(severity = c(3.25018430323761, 8.21019552826707, 10.2345631283889, 3.97861473573608, 2.49151725256104, 5.52900361815363, 55.2071093946671, 2.32037933918783, 3.70223446009639, 2.54604033976289, 6.11158768002453, 6.77828584824538, 2.95234684891201, 3.42869781905917, 1.42585469193667, 16.0747484046982, 34.6790705177556, 6.35006508638326, 21.3835553934895, 8.05182596903091, 5.51058496865505, 6.62574677139218, 18.5431647736137, 8.42472199298749, 3.36375810388373, 1.97372841937075, 8.31896832645395,  4.65269327269977, 6.22991152661561, 15.8544718751783, 1.90660480387344, 5.08052016589429, 20.2338335298909, 8.50945042127277, 1.51414101802446, 26.2729903771137, 5.53077768848019, 12.8038148444239, 3.12234414248935, 12.6786863038133, 26.2319370867102, 2.61240179627255, 8.23388110738683, 14.3826203214327, 11.595535364264, 97.6518578506433, 3.88736013960141, 40.0522894434289, 13.0286722381151, 13.8311206454621, 2.32138683407293, 16.2987548824861, 6.48548721511325, 18.3424463342478, 2.13908320122601,  20.6094599194298, 15.0090654547867, 20.8399356559801, 14.820113077459, 7.7047427230498, 4.39456178522343, 10.000704907942, 3.83333333333335, 11.4318867413853, 7.89010985916763, 21.1525423728813, 6.68434449076974, 30.7879775228089, 3.50698443368264, 1.57333784525088, 3.42869781905917, 6.61297948804958, 3.62752331453914, 1.97691919770155, 6.00848130742765, 60.5423027993827, 3.89628569263605, 3.49144306748366, 24.3750905239606, 11.595535364264, 7.70054828336092, 18.6975666270077, 2.09556927634091, 15.3288687440042,  7.24716796005598, 8.71416860168375, 8.80379237078557, 3.23719672489693, 2.6867931761598, 4.56424081767021, 2.21797125308475, 10.2054909549981, 3.2998707122004, 3.63083883463682, 5.4154303099926, 0.989943258036202, 26.0323383549274, 24.0264313596043, 1.27079897767722, 6.9055733274643, 6.01734276046511, 4.52444479739508, 5.18185818729858, 3.51960556662747, 5.63007253187119, 1.15126025566876, 18.0777099933802, 17.8171568613498, 6.30910836452448, 10.1390199646202, 5.46720789634529, 20.2819827606193,  3.62938031125651, 1.33160475087464, 8.75280601928286, 9.10988864573485, 13.1488401777766, 13.7673431302572, 21.0409114970367), prod = c(507.755867714392, 1705.49880158972, 3640.34113040821, 858.239175113401, 238.706492667227, 1244.6940148014, 3977.72626741407, 339.042388721234, 923.458086400708, 419.370659017813, 1158.70861783272, 1179.59095902181, 295.599071534232, 398.278208742789, 194.798500739898, 4650.15567576958, 6329.11241677931, 1028.0570456891, 4925.91370333093, 2022.3511913243, 783.15963920042,  716.208920204282, 2381.76958822984, 1254.23069689481, 778.9043298375, 161.157156502681, 1459.13900370654, 940.233384921433, 1198.83896632231, 3565.26547361682, 395.837386951839, 889.871919575969, 6996.9192914905, 2001.8432222017, 144.079015010842, 4547.94609766363, 1041.17426542942, 1515.78182421578, 448.256010275335, 3227.88109312385, 7761.31628488419, 250.126433743004, 983.315745749984, 3694.51237283626, 2512.9776843891, 7310.96143332019, 790.498601521711, 3996.2587837501, 1651.70598778014, 2804.27004030374,  307.274181420005, 2133.64570615031, 1381.62822639232, 3751.4044378629, 485.552835444503, 2465.6874345525, 3025.91221835444, 5158.1742720822, 2574.98910483359, 1273.35710229232, 598.036156054948, 1643.50834356176, 319.378521699767, 2181.69261318497, 1837.09807672159, 1995.27654536416, 1095.2915743086, 2019.78842929518, 493.82769157334, 154.231798231093, 398.278208742789, 1306.25665858632, 393.003321145881, 244.412035268987, 1215.07197775974, 5575.22264019978, 81.8997236216959, 804.215278351321, 3572.29089339365,  2512.9776843891, 1187.64667079267, 3881.32939729115, 281.095890630284, 1976.75638215586, 1972.34564060146, 2108.31162543769, 2531.23741386524, 727.63049151556, 421.413414189908, 885.516102680844, 299.807327188995, 1762.96442932355, 752.831017112768, 793.224382445508, 390.715569543075, 112.899610829257, 6219.34258924352, 3237.6574058879, 76.4770620527288, 1223.88524456515, 1344.24723795186, 790.08886120287, 753.308224886514, 495.744119100497, 1405.79935366988, 229.928716828958, 2151.99773055987, 1569.44091576891,  1030.48482889462, 1980.07816897896, 1133.82514266977, 2639.74185437294, 425.245731957402, 168.746508943713, 1094.91478503367, 1041.10131771391, 1505.42904059794, 952.396081074004, 1863.20884404754), lesion_level = structure(c(3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L,  4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L), levels = c("C1-C4", "C5-C8", "Paraplegia", "ASIA D"), class = "factor"), sex = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Male", "Female"), class = "factor"), SCIM = c(22, 2, 0, 8, 50, 17, 8, 64, 8, 17, 16, 13, 70, 62, 34, 12, 10, 29, 0, 3, 26, 6, 20, 18, 13, 70, 19, 27, 15, 11, 28, 15, 0, 6, 51, 15, 18, 14, 48, 11, 3, 14, 13, 18, 2, 10, 15, 8,  16, 9, 45, 19, 4, 8, 22, 22, 19, 15, 10, 23, 54, 14, 55, 21, 8, 70, 33, 21, 59, 49, 62, 27, 58, 40, 19, 0, 95, 16, 11, 2, 9, 7, 33, 22, 18, 17, 11, 15, 24, 27, 34, 8, 14, 12, 16, 21, 8, 14, 89, 42, 17, 15, 26, 29, 9, 14, 18, 4, 14, 9, 22, 12, 32, 46, 48, 35, 30, 27, 40)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "17", "18", "19", "21", "29", "32", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "51", "52",  "53", "54", "55", "57", "58", "60", "61", "62", "66", "68", "70", "71", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100", "101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", "110", "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", "119", "120", "121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127", "128", "129", "130", "131", "132", "133", "134", "135", "136", "137", "138", "139",  "140", "141", "142", "143", "144"), class = "data.frame")
```

I have generated the following plot:

The plot was generated using the following code:

```r
ggplot(totalamount, aes(x = lesion_level, y = severity, color = sex, fill = sex)) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_smooth(aes(group = sex), alpha = 0.05) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Male"=colores[1], "Female"=colores[4])) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Male"=colores[1], "Female"=colores[4])) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Gender"), color = guide_legend(title = "Gender")) +
  ylab(label = "name_serv") +
  xlab(label = "") +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 8))
```

[image]

But, I would like to compare the means of every group, for example in the two bars with C1-C4 to include a p value = 0.2 (for example) because it seems that the means of the two groups are similar.
I would like to include a p value for each group, I mean C5-C8, Paraplegia and ASIA D.

I found the library ggpubr really healpfull for this task. But I can not get the desired output.

For example to create something similar the code is the following:

```r
ggboxplot(totalamount, x="lesion_level", y="severity",
          color="sex", palette="jco", add="jitter", bxp.errorbar = TRUE) +
  stat_compare_means()
```

[image]

But in this case I am not clear what is the comparison considered in this p-value which group is being compared?
how to include 4 p values to analyze the comparison between each group?

Comment: Suggestion: `xlab(label = "")` means that there is an (invisible) x-axis label. If you use `xlab(label = NULL)` then you will collapse some of the blank-space by _removing_ the x-axis label. Immaterial to the question at hand.

Comment: Sorry, I do t understand what do you mean with accept an answer .. all the answers are welcome and helpful to learn and improve. All the answers are great thank you for your answer, I totally accept this answer.

Comment: And there it starts, my comment asking you to fix previous questions has been censured, since asking you to follow norms is considered anathema to fair conversation. Good luck, user2383060, for the sake of transparency and not abject self-promotion, due to the Stack META-gods I must recuse myself completely. I hope you got what you needed from my answer. Please do consider going back, though, you may find others are less willing to help when users provide no palpable gratitude for the volunteered time.

Comment: Sorry I was just trying to accept the answer, I thought that addin the flag is accept...... I clicked in the flag and add a comment that I accept the answer. I am really sorry .. now I am trying to quit .Accepting answers is new for me ...

Comment: That's fine. I don't know what "addin" you're talking about, but ... you had previously accepted two answers from among your 39 questions, and had another twenty-something questions with answers but none accepted. As far as I know, it is a manual process. Just like upvoting, it is "just a click away".

Comment: I am really sorry, I just put like I never thought that this was accepting and answer... I am really sorry... What I did was put a click in the flag... Because I thought that doing that was accept an answer... But it seems that is not correct, now I can't see the answer and the solution that someone posted, how to correct this mistake, I am really sorry... This is not easy for me, I am trying to ask questions about what is difficult to understand for me.... I am really sorry for real...how to correct this misunderstanding from my side??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256102/discussion-between-user3483060-and-r2evans).

Comment: @user3483060 You may find this useful on how to accept an answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251399/12109788

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`kruskal.test` only does a simple one-deep comparison. If you're trying to calculate the p-value between `sex`es for each of your `lesion_level`, then I suggest we calculate that first.

I'll demo in `dplyr`, though mostly for convenience, other summarize-by-group options exist.

```r
library(dplyr)
res <- group_by(totalamount, lesion_level) %>%
  summarize(pv = kruskal.test(severity ~ sex, data = cur_data())$p.value) %>%
  mutate(
    lbl = formatC(signif(pv, digits=3), digits=3, format="fg", flag="#"),
    lbl = paste0(if_else(lesion_level == "C1-C4", "Kruskal-Wallis\np = ", "\np = "),
                 lbl)
  )
res
# # A tibble: 4 × 3
#   lesion_level    pv lbl                        
#   <fct>        <dbl> <chr>                      
# 1 C1-C4        0.867 "Kruskal-Wallis\np = 0.867"
# 2 C5-C8        0.487 "\np = 0.487"              
# 3 Paraplegia   0.721 "\np = 0.721"              
# 4 ASIA D       0.320 "\np = 0.320"
```

I used the `formatC(signif(..), ..)` to produce a simple 3-significant-digit display robust across different orders of magnitude (borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3443955/3358272). While it does little *here*, if you had one group where the p-value was near `0.000237` then you could see the difference:

```r
formatC(signif(c(res$pv, 0.000273), digits=3), digits=3, format="fg", flag="#")
# [1] "0.867"    "0.487"    "0.721"    "0.320"    "0.000273"
```

This allows us to plot it as:

```r
gg <- ggplot(totalamount, aes(x = lesion_level, y = severity, color = sex, fill = sex)) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_smooth(aes(group = sex), alpha = 0.05) +
  geom_text(aes(x = lesion_level, label = lbl), y = Inf, vjust = 2,
            data = res, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  # scale_color_manual(values = c("Male"=colores[1], "Female"=colores[4])) +
  # scale_fill_manual(values = c("Male"=colores[1], "Female"=colores[4])) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Gender"), color = guide_legend(title = "Gender")) +
  ylab(label = "name_serv") +
  xlab(label = "") +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 8))
suppressWarnings(print(gg))
```

(I commented out the `scale_*` expressions since we don't have `colores`.)

[image: ggplot with Kruskal-Wallis p-values over each pair of boxplots]

The aesthetics of my additions can easily be improved, but I think the premise should be clear.